# Call a bash scripts with a bash script. Check the exit code and ignore the output of the called bash script

Tags: bash

I wrote a script, where I call other scripts (without a parameter) and than check the return value of the script (it should be 1).

```
yourfilenames=$(ls ./)
for FILE in $yourfilenames
do
Points=0
./$FILE 
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
    Points=$(($Points + 1))
fi
done
```

The problem is a script like this:

```
Usage()
{
clear
    printf "${red}ERROR (An Error has occured.)${reset}\n\n"
    sleep 1.5
    
    read -n 1 -s -r -p "Please press a key to continue..."
    clear
}

if [ $# -gt 2 ] || [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    Usage
    exit 1
fi
```

And also:

```
echo "What do u want to know?(Quit with "q")"
while (true)
do
    read input_string
    case $input_string in
.
.
.

q)  break
    ;;

Q)  break
    ;;

*)  echo "This function is not possible"
    ;;
    esac
done
echo
echo "Bye"

exit 0
```

My script should check the return value of like 50 scripts automated, but my script is stopping because I need to press a key to continue it (In the example above).

How can my script "ignore" these Input requests? Can my script also ignore the "sleep 1.5" ?

I tried it with `>/dev/null` but that doesnt work, I just dont see the output on my console. I still need to press a key.

Comment: Why do you do `FILE=$eachfile`? You can just use `./$eachfile`, there's no need for a second variable.

Comment: Ah yeah, I wanted to change that. Doing it now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the `yes` command to the command. It provides a continuous supply of `y` answers to any questions.

Also, don't parse the output of `ls`. It will fail if any of the filenames have whitespace in them.

And `Points` needs to be initialized before the loop. You're setting it back to `0` before each script.

```
Points=0

for eachfile in *
do
    if ! yes | ./"$eachfile" >/dev/null
    then
        ((Points++))
    fi
done
```

Needless to say, you should only do this if you know that the scripts don't do anything dangerous based on the response to the prompts.

You can override the `sleep` commands by creating a directory with a symlink `sleep` that points to `/bin/true`, and put this directory at the beginning of `$PATH`.